# How to use phatomjs from PHP to exec Javascript on a downloaded page?

Tags: php, javascript, phantomjs

I am working in an "autobrowsing" script. My script should be able to download certain pages and then parse these for finding certain values, and so generate an output. Also the server needs authentication.

I have been able to get these pages using CURL lib from PHP, including the authentication part, but the problem is that the contents of these pages are generated within javascript functions, so after downloading them with CURL functions, most of the contents are missing because the JS code isn't executed.

So, what I need is the DOM *after* the JS is executed. I have spent sometime figuring out the best approach for this, and I am not sure to have found it. Anyway It didn't work for me yet, so...

What I did was install phantomjs on my Linux box, and try to use it just for execute the JS code in the pages downloaded. So, I download the page using CURL and save it as "test.html" file, then I exec "phantomjs test.html", but all I get is this:

```
$ phantomjs test.html 
undefined:1 SyntaxError: Parse error
```

And it does nothing more, like it were hanged.

test.html contains both, html and JS code within script tags, you know, as every other so common webpage with JS.

Anyway and to be sure that it was not a problem with test.html, I downloaded the index.html page of google.com with wget, and I have obtained the same result:

```
$ phantomjs index.html 
undefined:1 SyntaxError: Parse error
```

So I concluded that I must be doing something wrong...

Any help is welcomed. :-)

Bests,

Answer (score 3):

The reason `phantomjs index.html` will not work is because the first parameter you pass into phantomjs is the phantomjs script you wish to execute, not a html file.  I would recommend using phantomjs to open the webpage directly as oppose to passing a html file into it.  There are quite a few examples of how to do this, even look at the one on the home page of http://phantomjs.org/.  For more advanced features see the [API](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference).  If you have any more specific questions then ask here.

Comment: I need to send some headers within each HTTP server request for performing authentication getting each page that I need to parse, that's the reason I download the page before instead of passing the URL to phantomjs.

Comment: @Fran - phantomjs lets you modify headers as well, you can pass those into the phantomjs script as params

Comment: Will take a look on that ASAP. I am considering giving this up anyway, the time and effort it is consuming is too much for the benefit.

Comment: You might be right.  On the other hand I have saved myself a tonne of time using PhantomJS to scrape webpages because it makes it sooo easy to manipulate and traverse the dom